# Integration Addition Question

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

[image]

So, I was given the following question, and I'm a bit lost. I understand the properties behind flipping the bounds of the integrals and I understand that there has to be some of that in this problem, but I'm a bit lost on how to start it/if the work I've been doing has at all been correct? I'd appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.   $$\int_0^{-5}(6g(x)+2)dx=6\int_0^{-5}g(x)+\int_0^{-5}2dx,$$

$$\int_{-5}^0g(x)dx=-\int_0^{-5}g(x)dx,$$

and $$\int_{-5}^3g(x)dx=\int_{-5}^0g(x)dx+\int_0^3g(x)dx$$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I believe so, after finishing the work I got the answer to be $58$? Some confirmation on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I got $\color{red}-58$

Comment: @joe - Please notice that the integration bounds have been reversed in the last integral of the question. Anyway, you are quite close to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $$\int_0^{-5} f(x) dx =- \int_{-5}^0 f(x)dx = -\left( \int_{-5}^3 f(x)dx - \int_0^3 f(x)dx \right)$$